# Moksha for the Soul of Brahma

Tags: philosophy, moksha, brahma, atma, lokas

The life of Brahma is 100 years of Brahma.  More information on [Hindu Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology#Description)

We are in 51st year of the current Brahma's Life Year.

I also know that after Brahma dies, Brahma (the soul in that post) is reborn.

My Question is:

> Is the current soul of Brahma reborn as Brahma again or some one else’s soul is reborn as Brahma?

I've heard that Lord Hanuman will be the next Brahma.

Then what will happen with the current soul of Brahma? Will it attain Moksha?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to tell exactly. Some people say that Brahma is a jiva like everyone else and so the normal rules apply. Some people say Brahma is not a regular jiva and he is already liberated soul serving Sri Vishnu. Some people say that Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are just three different forms of the same immortal Brahman and therefore by that logic there is no such thing as Moksha for Brahman who is One without a Second. All the best!

Comment: Which Scripture says we are in 51st year of Brahma?

Comment: @AnilKumar See verse 37 of this chapter of the Srimad Bhagavatam: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/11

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes, the current Brahma attains Moksha at the end of his life.**  As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7588/36), the Srimad Bhagavatam [describes](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/32/chapter-view) what happens to the inhabitants of Brahmaloka, including Brahma himself, at the end of the Mahakalpa:

> Worshipers of the Hiraṇyagarbha expansion of the Personality of Godhead remain within this material world until the end of two parārdhas, when Lord Brahmā also dies. After experiencing the inhabitable time of the three modes of material nature, known as two parārdhas, Lord Brahmā closes the material universe, which is covered by layers of earth, water, air, fire, ether, mind, ego, etc., and goes back to Godhead. The yogīs who become detached from the material world by practice of breathing exercises and control of the mind reach the planet of Brahmā, which is far, far away. After giving up their bodies, they enter into the body of Lord Brahmā, and therefore **when Brahmā is liberated and goes to the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who is the Supreme Brahman, such yogīs can also enter into the kingdom of God**.

In my question and answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8653/36), I discuss a couple more quotes, proffered by the ancient sage Badari, in defense of the view that the inhabitants of Brahmaloka attain Moksha.  First of all, there is [this verse](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15021.htm) from the Mundaka Upanishad:

> Having well ascertained the object of the knowledge of the Vedânta, and having purified their nature by the Yoga of renunciation, all anchorites, enjoying the highest immortality, become free at the time of the great end (death) in the worlds of Brahmâ.

And there's verse 12.269 of the Kurma Purana:

> When the pralaya has come and the end of the Highest, **they all together with Brahma enter the highest place**.

Note that the inhabitants of Brahmaloka don't just automatically attain Moksha as a birthright.  Rather, it is through meditation on the supreme Brahman while they're in Brahmaloka that they ultimately attain Moksha.  See my question and answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8657/36).

To answer your other question, yes, when a new Mahakalpa begins, someone else is born as Brahma.  I'm not sure whether Hanuman being the next Brahma has a basis in Hindu scripture, but a question was asked about it [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7311/36).

Comment: since I can't comment yet, adding this Note - not all inhabitants of brahma loka attain moksha. Act of Kanya daanam can also send one to brahmaloka ('kanya kanaka...brahma lokam jigeeshaya'), but they could return. it is the naishtika yogis who attain moksha along with brahma at end of kalpa.