# How do the Vedas describe Moksha?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, upanishads, moksha

It is commonly seen that in many Vedanta texts and discourses we hear of moksha. I have also asked a related question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/is-moksha-related-to-immortality).

**I want to know how does the Vedas describe moksha?**

**Are there any specific statements in the Vedas which talk about  the word moksha and its nature?**

(**P.S:** Kindly limit the references from **actual vedas or [mukhya upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukhya_Upanishads)** in a direct manner. Please avoid opinion and commentaries of sanyasins/sadhus etc.)

Answer (score 7):

**The concept of Moksha in the famous Mahamrityunjaya mantra**

> Trayambakam YajAmahe sugandhim Pushtivardhanam | UrvArukam Iva
>   BandhanAn Mrityor MukshIya mA AmritAt ||
>
> .....................
>
> We adore the Father of the three worlds, Trayambaka, bestower of all
>   sided fragrance of grace, increaser of fullness and strength; May i be
>   detached from the bondage of death like a ripe cucumber from the stem,
>   but not from **immortality**.
>
> **Rig Veda 7.59.12.**

The Seer here seeks Moksha for himself and for others from Lord Shiva.

**Concept of Moksha in the Purusha Suktam:**

> VedAhametam purusham mahAntam (1) Adityavarnam tamasah parastAt (2)
>
> Tam evam vidvAn amrita iha bhavati (3) NAnyah panthAvidyate ayanAya
>   (4)
>
> .........
>
> I have known the mighty Purusha (1) Who is refulgent as the Sun beyond
>   darkness. (2) Knowing Him thus in this life itself, **one transcends
>   death (3). There is no other path leading to the attainment of
>   liberation. (4).**
>
> **Taitiriya Samhita 3.12.17.**

These mantras talk about the only method of liberation and which is knowing the Purusha or knowing the self. And they also say that there are no other ways.

Comment: So moksha is equal to immortality ?

Comment: Yes nothing much in Vedas other than these.

Comment: Is it also about staying in heavens or any other loka till eternity?

Comment: I don't know about that. @RakeshJoshi