# What is the Vedic definition of Moksha?

Tags: rig-veda, moksha, meditation, vivekananda, sannyasa

I've heard sannyasa, the 4th Vedic ashrama, is meant for the attainment of ***moksha***. Thus, the sannyasin is expected to go to a solitary mountain cave or a dense-forest retreat where he must get lost in deep meditation till death and thus attain the desired moksha. Evidently, sannyasa is meant for those that are disgusted with life, and moksha seems to mean ***death*** through yoga-meditation. Nevertheless, it is, most probably, ***Vivekananda*** that invented a new & novel ***thesis***, namely, that sannyasa is also love of life, and so the sannyasin need ***N***ot abandon the worldly life and embrace death for moksha. The sannyasin is ***free***, by this thesis, to lead a worldly life and relish, like all worldly people, all the ease & pleasure, both sensuous & ***sensual***, of life, and yet he's certain to attain the moksha, the only condition being that he has to enjoy all the ease & pleasure of life with spiritual ' ***detachment*** '. The problem with this novel thesis is it makes the ***essential*** distinction between a sannyasin and a ***N***on-sannyasin vanish outright.

Comment: The word "Moksha" derived from "Moha Kshaya", which literally means the end of delusion.

Comment: Related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/how-do-the-vedas-describe-moksha