# Per the Vedas, can a person really step on another planet physically?

Tags: vedas

In my school days, one of the Sanskrit lesson named "anthariksha vijayaha", has a statement saying

> It is mentioned in the Vedas that a person(physically) cannot step on any other
>   planet/satellite but some persons have already reached the moon and
>   came back.

Does Vedas say that a human can't step on other celestial bodies?

So, has that particular sentence (in Vedas) been proved wrong (by the [Moon landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing))?

Answer (score 6):

The Vedas are eternal, i am not sure which part of the vedas mentions this, but it widely acknowledged that unless and until one performs certain purification karma's which are required to attain a certain planet he cannot reach there.

The species on a particular planet are made of the elements benevolent to it.

Vedas mention that one need to have certain qualifications to attain higher planets.

So the people who had gone to moon must have attained the qualification in their previous lives(provided the people landing on moon is true).

The planets mentioned as navagrahas or other higher or lower planets/lokas are to be known fully what the sages had mentioned in the vedas. Whether they are in physical plane/ spiritual plane. We need to understand what the sages actually meant of different lokas before considering the validity of the vedas.

No one of the present can perfectly say about the different lokas given in various scriptures, they can be best known from compiler himself the sage Bhagavan Veda-Vyasa who is believed to be a chiranjeevi. Their are no concrete evidences of people contacting veda-vyas.

How the sages might have known about different lokas thousands of years ago and how could they describe them ?
How did they prescribe the qualifications required ?

All the conception of lokas/planets are nowadays run on the belief/faith system as the ability to tap that knowledge is lost from the present generation.

So one should be able to meditate and vibrate your brain to a particular frequency to get the knowledge you required from this infinite realm.

"The description about different lokas is given in the atharveda, Srimad bhagavatam canto 2 chapter 5 from sloka number 38, in vishnu purana chapter 7 etc."

As per SB Each and every loka has some specific attributes ie. the people who attained the requirements/qualifications will attain it.

Out of the 14 mentioned lokas in above mentioned scriptures, the 7 heavenly planets and their attributes are
1 Satya-loka: Brahma's loka. Satya-loka planetary system is not eternal. Abode of Truth or of Brahma, where atman are released from the necessity of rebirth.

2 Tapa-loka: Abode of tapas or of other deities. Ayohnija devadas live here.

3 Jana-loka: Abode of the sons of God Brahma.

4 Mahar-loka: The abode of great sages and enlightened beings like Markendeya and other rishies.

5 Svar-loka: Region between the sun and polar star, the heaven of the god Indra. Indra, devatas, Rishies, Gandharvas and Apsaras live here: a heavenly paradise of pleasure, where all the 330 million Hindu gods (Deva) reside along with the king of gods, Indra.

6 Bhuvar-loka (aka Pitri Loka): Sun, planets, stars. Space between earth and the sun, inhabited by semi-divine beings. The a real region, the atmosphere, the life-force.

7 Bhur-loka: Man and animals live here. The Vishnu Purana says that the earth is merely one
of thousands of billions of inhabited worlds like itself to be found in the universe.

Different realms of Patala are ruled by different demons and Nagas; usually with the Nagas headed by Vasuki assigned to the lowest realm.Vayu Purana records each realm of Patala has cities in it.

The 7 hellish planets are

8 Atala-loka: Atala is ruled by Bala - a son of Maya - who possesses mystical powers. By one yawn, Bala created three types of women - svairiṇīs ("self-willed"), who like to marry men from their own group; kāmiṇīs ("lustful"), who marry men from any group, and the puḿścalīs ("whorish"), who keep changing their partners. When a man enters Atala, these women enchant him and serve him an intoxicating cannabis drink that induces sexual energy in the man. Then, these women enjoy sexual play with the traveller, who feels to be stronger than ten thousand elephants and forgets impending death.

9 Vitala-loka: Vitala is ruled by the god Hara-Bhava - a form of Shiva, who dwells with attendant ganas including ghosts and goblins as the master of gold mines. The residents of this realm are adorned with gold from this region.

10 Sutala-loka: Sutala is the kingdom of the pious demon king Bali.

11 Talatala-loka: Talātala is the realm of the demon-architect Maya, who is well-versed in sorcery. Shiva, as Tripurantaka, destroyed the three cities of Maya but was later pleased with Maya and gave him this realm and promised to protect him.

12 Mahatala-loka: Mahātala is the abode of many-hooded Nagas (serpents) - the sons of Kadru, headed by the Krodhavasha (Irascible) band of Kuhaka, Taksshaka, Kaliya and Sushena. They live here with their families in peace but always fear Garuda, the eagle-man.

13 Rasatala-loka: Rasātala is the home of the demons - Danavas and Daityas, who are mighty but cruel. They are the eternal foes of Devas (the gods). They live in holes like serpents.

14 Patala-loka: The lowest realm is called Patala or Nagaloka, the region of the Nagas, ruled by Vasuki. Here live several Nagas with many hoods. Each of their hood is decorated by a jewel, whose light illuminates this realm.

Many contemporary explanations are given for these lokas so as to how to understand them and yet it is difficult to comprehend for us as no concrete conclusion has come out.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Very nice answer, why isn't it upvoted so far?  Can you explain the moon landing missions from U.S. during 1969-72 keeping aside the useless conspiracy theories? Also some of the hellish planets appears heavenly with today's standards! @KeshavSrinivasan, though he has mentioned Vishnu Purana & Bhagvadam as source, I agree that the link should be helpful.

Comment: @iammilind The sources were added after my comment.

Comment: @iammilind You may be interested to know that ISKCON either believes the moon landings were faked or believes that the place that the astronauts went to wasn't the "true" moon that Hindu scripture talks about.  Personally, I think that insofar as Hindu scripture says that you need certain Punya to attain the moon (and I'm not sure if Hindu scripture actually says that), it would presumably be talking about what souls need to do to get there after death, not about what it takes to go there physically before you die.

Comment: @iammilind You may also be interested in my answer here, which is related to souls going to the moon and to the Panchagni Vidya that we've discussed so much lately: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6925/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, from my upvote I see that I have already visited that answer. Regarding ISCKON, they are just 1 of the believers of conspiracy theories against moon landing. Mostly it accepted about their genuineness. Even now India has reached till Mars without men. Just a matter of few years for manned missions.

Comment: @iammilind Here are a bunch of quotes of Prabhupada concerning the moon landings: http://www.harekrsna.org/moon-landing.htm He thinks the astronauts may have landed on Rahu and mistaken it for the moon.  This is one of the numerous areas where I disagree with ISKCON's view of astronomy.

Comment: The conspiracy theories against the 1st moon mission had some compelling reasons to believe that they didn't land on the moon but a studio setup to win the coldwar race(to fullfill the target imposed by president JFK) but the HD pictures of (released recently) later Apollo missions had some reasons to believe to an extent.

Comment: They are many questions regarding apollo missions of US, they visited only one face of the moon(that which is visible to the viewers on the earth) and the dark side of it is not known(or they are hiding something which they had seen probably an Alien existence).
Not only moon, the astronauts of the International space station and those of shuttle missions reported unusual space crafts moving at randomly high speeds in the space between earth and moon. The US activities in Area 51 are top secret and US is hiding information from general public about UFO's, Aliens.

Comment: These aliens are beings with supernatural powers who taught the ancient civilizations how to live on this planet(which can be known from the cave paintings of alien contact from mayan and egyptian ciivilizations).These beings are considered as GOD's and were worshiped by these civilizations and these GOD'S interbred with people to bring out advanced people to rule the world(acc. to ancient alien theorists).There are many evidences from ancient Indian civilization where rulers were born from GODS. We need to have broader perspective by interpreting scriptures from archaeological finds.

Comment: The lokas which i mentioned in my post are easily travelled by great sages like narada and others.These they had done with their physical bodies and they could anywhere in the wink of an eye(teleportation), these claims are supernatural to comprehend for ordinary humans. But there are none today who could explain these. NASA & other nations are trying to improvise day by day their knowledge of space, time can answer our ancient scriptural claims which keep on improving their acceptance.The movie Interstellar had provided some insights which were similar to those mentioned in our scriptures.

Comment: I can't tell which part of your answer is sourced from other texts and what is your commentary. Looks like you referenced a portion of your answer from the wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patala. Nothing wrong with it, but you should probably list it as a reference in your answer and also use blockquoting for that part.

Comment: I disagree that person with past karmic connections can only step on such planets. Srimad Bhagavatam clearly describes the distance from one loka to another loka. It's just that the inhabitants of those planets cannot be seen by us because of the difference in dimensions but that doesn't mean that those planets cannot be reached, they can be because those planets exists physically in the normal dimensions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I too would disagree with Prabhupada's claims that they went to Rahu ... AFAIK,  Rahu is a shadowy planet (i.e. subtle or ethereal planet) and not a physical one. If it was physical then astronomers would have discovered it already along with Ketu. Prabhupada made a lot of assumptions. He lacked that spiritual vision or psychic powers (siddhas) that yogis normally possess. And yet the ISKCONITES say, that people in bhakti yoga, after attaining GOD gets to know everything. (All is revealed to such people by GOD). If u ask me, that doesn't seems to be the case with Prabhupada.