# What Hindu Scriptures say that Universe has diameter of fifty crore yojana?

Tags: scripture, puranas, history, prabhupada

Srila Prabhupada [said](http://www.harekrsna.org/moon-landing.htm) that humans never went to Chandraloka as it requires enlightened soul and opined humans might have gone to other planet such as Rahu. He said whole universe is ***panchshat-koti-yojana*** which means fifty crore yojana or ***panchashat*** or four billion miles in diameter.

Can i know which scriptures (preferably vedas or upanishads or puranas; not the work of Astronomers such as Aryabhatta) cite this calculation?

Comment: My answer here gives various distances: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7262/36  I should mention that I profoundly disagree with the views of Prabhupada and ISKCON on Hindu cosmology, as I discuss in the comments section of that answer.

Comment: @Keshav, extremely informative answer. I would like to add one thing, in my understanding, the lokas- Bhur, bhuvah, Svah etc. Do not refer to physical planets. Infact the entire physical universe is included in Bhu-loka. Other lokas are subtle realms and are cosmos on their own. Hence, it needs a subtle body to go into those lokas. In fact it is said that, when after death one goes to Pitr loka, he gains a new different kind of body there.

Comment: @NithinSridhar Yeah, I wholeheartedly agree that Bhuloka encompasses the entire physical universe.  That's why I ended my answer with "I should add that while these passages discuss spatial separations, I don't think these Lokas are actually in our physical universe; in addition to spatial separation they might also be located in separate universes".

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Are there any scriptures citing that humans cannot land on Moon and Mars?

Comment: @AnilKumar I'm not aware of any scriptures that say that, but a question was asked about it here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8708/36

Comment: Fifty crore yojana is not necessarily 4 billion miles... Jains take 1 yojana = 6400 km for astronomical data... I think that is correct for large astronomical range... I think Bhu Bhuva Swaha and all 14 lokas are in seperate dimension hence can't reached by simple spaceship.. I think magical spaceship is needed...I assume entire physical universe or a galaxy falls under Bhuloka...uranus neptune and pluto are mentioned by vyas in mahabharat I think as shyama shewta trikshuka respectively..

Comment: @Tezz 6400 km is approximately radius of Earth. Is it mentioned anywhere about size of earth (diameter) as 2 Yojanas? Yojana being 6400 km is very large distance. Do you know wherein Mahabhartha Uranus, neptune and Pluto are mentioned?

Comment: @The Destroyer In Jain cosmology whose root is vedic 1 yojan=4000 miles= 6400 km see [here](http://www.worldlibrary.org/articles/yojana) For the mention of Uranus neptune and pluto see [here](https://agarwaltv.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/uranus-neptune-pluto-mentioned-in-mahabharata-3100-bce/)

Comment: Yes yojana as 6400 km is too large for earthly calculation.. as 100 yojan distance of Rama setu would make huge.. but in interplanetary calculation I think 8 km as yojana is not sufficient..

Comment: Where is scientific speculation in this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Prabhupada is stating diameter of Universe from [this verse](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/20/38) of Srimad Bhagvatam:

> एतावाळ् लोक-विन्यासो मान-लक्षण-संस्थाभिर् विचिन्तितः कविभिः स तु ।
>   **पञ्चाशत्-कोटि-गणितस्य भू-गोलस्य** तुरीय-भागो ’यं लोकालोकाचलः ।। (SB 5.20.38)
>  
>   Learned scholars have thus described the planetary systems and their particular symptoms, measurements and locations. By mathematical calculation it comes that Lokaloka is situated at one fourth (Turiya Bhaga) of **this Physical Universe (Bhumandala) which has diameter of 50 crore yojana (PanchaShat Koti).**

That verse states:

> पञ्चाशत्-कोटि-गणितस्य भू-गोलस्य।
>   Bhu Gola (Mandala) is mathematically calculated as 50 crore (Yojanas).

As a side note it is not necessary that 50 crore Yojanas is equal to 4 billion miles. Value of Yojana is a debated value. Also it may be cosmic Yojana. Also it maybe diameter of BhuMandala during Saraswata Kalpa as Bhagvatam narrates the Story of Saraswata Kalpa. Also the term Koti usually means millions but it isn't necessary that it always means millions.

Comment: Is Bhu Gola  earth or Universe?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Neither earth nor universe, it is galaxy.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria If it's Galaxy, it will be spiral not "Gola" shaped.

Comment: @The Destroyer Bhu Gola generally means Earth but in this verse it means Bhu Mandala which can be either entire physical universe (or galaxy).. I think Bhu Mandala means entire physical universe..

Comment: @Tezz - Superb Answer.

Comment: For this to be talked, the world should be accepted as real to start with ?